# Localhost xampp? datatype issue

Tags: php, arrays, xampp, arguments

Uncaught TypeError: trim(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\required_valid_form.php:52
Is there any Syntax issue, which is collapsing with each other?

```
<?php
    $name=$email=$website=$comment=$gender="";
    $nameErr=$emailErr=$genderErr="";
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
            $nameErr = "Name is Required";
        } else {
            $name = test_input($_POST=["name"]);
        }
        if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
            $emailErr = "Your Email is Required";
        } else {
            $email = test_input($_POST=["email"]);
        }
        if(empty($_POST["website"])) {
            $website = "";
        } else {
            $website = test_input($_POST=["website"]);
        }
        if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
            $comment = "";
        } else {
            $comment = test_input($_POST=["comment"]);
        }
        if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
            $genderErr = "It is required!";
        } else {
            $gender = test_input($_POST=["gender"]);
        }
    }
    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }    
?>
```

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with the `$_POST=["name"]` construct? You're destroying input data with that. `=` is the [assignment operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php).

Comment: how to find out where to use assignment op or other operators? would you like to recommend me something?

Comment: Read the manual and go through some PHP 101 tutorials. In general, if you want to _set_ a variable, use `=` and if you want to read a variable, don't use `=`. This is the very basics of PHP (and most other languages).

Comment: PHP 101 Tutorials ? where are they ?

Answer (score 0):

**Issue : $_POST=["name"]** I was using assignment operator here which is not right.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .error {
            color:#FF0000;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
       
    <body>
    <?php
            $name=$email=$website=$comment=$gender="";
            $nameErr=$emailErr=$genderErr="";
            if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    
                if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
                    $nameErr = "Name is Required";
                } else {
                    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
                }
                if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
                    $emailErr = "Your Email is Required";
                }
                    else {
                    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
                    }
                if(empty($_POST["website"])) {
                    $website="";
                }
                else {
                    $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
                }
                if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
                    $comment="";
                }
                else {
                    $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
                }
                if(empty($_POST["gender"])) {
                    $genderErr = "It is required!";
                }
                else {
                    $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
                }
            }
            function test_input($data) {
                $data = trim($data);
                $data = stripslashes($data);
                $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
                return $data;
            }    
    ?>
        <p><span class="error">Required Field *</span> </p>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
            Name : <input type="text" name="name"><span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr; ?></span>
            <br><br>
            Email : <input type="email" name="email"><span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr; ?> </span>
            <br><br>
            Website: <input type="text" name="website" id=""><br><br>
            Comment: <textarea name="comment" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br>
            Gender :  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Other">Other <span class="error">*<?php echo $genderErr; ?></span>
                        <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Here">
        </form>
        <?php
        echo "<h2>Your Input</h2>";
        echo $name;
        echo "<br><br>";
        echo $email;
        echo "<br><br>";
        echo $website;
        echo "<br><br>";
        echo $comment;
        echo "<br><br>";
        echo $gender;
        
        ?>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```